# Xcode 8 :unknown type name 'CABasicAnimation';did you mean 'CAAnimation'

Tags: ios10, xcode8, cabasicanimation

Xcode8:I'm trying to CMD+B Project in generic ios Device.
But show Error:
unknown type name 'CABasicAnimation';did you mean 'CAAnimation';
else simulators OK.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are missing a `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` at the top of your file or QuartzCore isn't linked at all (Check at Project -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries).

And it's always a good idea to delete Derived Data contents and rebuild the project from scratch in those cases.

Comment: TKS,I have solved the problem.The reason is that the contents of the file <CAAnimation.h> are missing in iOS 10.0 Frameworks else Simulator file is OK.